# multiple images in a loop fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have stripped back my Fiddle to show my issue.

I have a Rectagle that I am looping so it gives a different name with multiple instances. I can add and remove the rectangles fine. My issue is that I am replacing this rectangle with an image and I can get it to loop ok, but it will only remove 1 image and not them all. I think I am doing something wrong with the name, but i can not see the wood through the trees.

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/wayneker/48agpn5n/)

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var land = [];
var turret = [];
var wh=[];
var op=[];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Outpost Level Dropmenu Select
$(document).ready(function () {$('#method').change(
function () {
   var method = $('option:selected').val();

                            if (this.value == "0") {            
            for (var i=0; i<96; i++){
            canvas.remove(land[i]);
      canvas.remove(turret[i]);
      canvas.remove(wh[i]);
      canvas.remove(op[i]);
};

}                       else if (this.value == "1") { 
//Clear All
            for (var i=0; i<96; i++){
            canvas.remove(land[i]);
      canvas.remove(turret[i]); 
      canvas.remove(wh[i]);
};
//Add Buildings
      for (var i=0; i<40; i++){
            land[i] = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'green',left: 25,top: 25,width: 25,height: 25,    
        perPixelTargetFind: true,hasBorders: false,hasControls:false, hasRotatingPoint: false,
});
            canvas.add(land[i])
};
            for (var i=0; i<6; i++){
            turret[i] = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'brown',left: 75,top: 25,width: 15,height: 15,    
        perPixelTargetFind: true,hasBorders: false,hasControls: false,hasRotatingPoint: false,
});
            canvas.add(turret[i])
};

            for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
            fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/baseplanner2/images/buildings/warehouse.png', function(myImgwh) {wh[i] = myImgwh.set({ left: 25, top: 75 ,width:25,height:25, hasControls: false, hasRoatatingPoint: false,stroke: 'blue',strokeWidth: 1,
});
            canvas.add(wh[i]); 
});
};

}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 3 of your images are added async with a reference to `i` and the reference to `i` is 3 when all images are added. if you look at your 'wh' array you have a bunch of undefineds and then only 1 object added to the array. that is why you can only delete one object.

[this JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/f2yej9fk/) just gets a new id in the callback which sets the array up correctly and then they can be deleted since you will now have all the proper references.

Comment: ty for this. i also charged the var i =0 to  let i=o and it worked

Answer (score 0):

if it's acceptable to clear the whole canvas then this you can use the `context` -fiddle here https://fiddle.jshell.net/2xozu3wk/ as discussed in this query [How to undraw, hide, remove, or delete an image from an html canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576755/how-to-undraw-hide-remove-or-delete-an-image-from-an-html-canvas) I think all but one of your images is being committed to the canvas and images paint pixels in a manner that's not so easy to clean up. Alternatively you can blank the canvas and reinstate elements you wish to retain but be prepared for a flicker?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

.
.
.

if (this.value == "0") {            
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);     
}
```

don't know if that helps

Comment: i cant blank the canvas as other elements need it. this fiddle is to show what i have done wrong...