# How to show different canvas show on different button press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a canvas in which 4 buttons and one canvas.

All four buttons have different canvas.
like rectangle square and circle.

when i click on circle button then in canvas circle show.and after that when i click on rectangle button then in canvas rectangle canvas show.

My main question is when i am clicking on circle button they show circle but when i click on rectangle button that i want to show only rectangle canvas and hide all circle and square button canvas.

so what should i do to show different canvas on different buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shared any snippet, I can only provide you with the ways to do it: [How to undraw, hide, remove, or delete an image from an html canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576755/how-to-undraw-hide-remove-or-delete-an-image-from-an-html-canvas)
Hope it helps you!

Comment: karan bro jab question samjh na ae toh rply nhi karna chahiye... khamo kha point kam kr deye.. @karandhir