# How do I get rid of the trail of images that are drawn as my character moves?

Tags: javascript

How do I get rid of the trail of images that are drawn as my character moves?

```
var avatarX = 0; //Variable
var avatarY = 267; //Variable
var avatarImage; //Variable
var counter = 1; //Variable
var XWIDTH = 0; //Variable
var WIDTH = 400; //Variable
var dx = 5; //Variable
var tt; //Variable
```

Code to set up the game canvas

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);

function setUpGame() {
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
avatarImage = new Image();

avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png";


gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, avatarY);
var tt = setInterval(function(){counTer()},1000);
setInterval(handleTick, 25);
}
```

Code to detect button presses

```
function KeyDown(evt, switchTEMPO) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
          if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
             avatarX += dx;
          }
        break;
       case 37: /*Arrow to the right*/
          if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
             avatarX -= dx;
          }
        break;
  }
}
```

Code to implement a counter

```
function counTer() {
  if(counter == 60) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
    gameCanvas.width = 400;
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").font = "18px Iceland";
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").textBaseline = "top";
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").fillText("Seconds: " + counter, 5, 5);
  }
}
```

Code to draw character to the screen

```
function handleTick() {

    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, avatarX, avatarY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not clearing the canvas. Before drawing the next frame, you should do the following:

```
// Clear a specific area of the context
context.clearRect (x, y, width, height);
```

For example, if your canvas has a width of `300px` and a height of `100px`,

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 100);
```

Comment: I think the bit of code you recommended only works when you are drawing a box/pixel of a certain size. In my case I'm drawing a picture that I've got stored in variable avatarImage. But please prove me wrong as I'm still learning to code in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think you can tell canvas to delete a specific image object. The canvas only stores pixels - to remove the pixels of an image you have to write over them. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458244/removing-an-image-from-a-canvas-in-html5) for more information.